# Invalid or Corrupt file after force closing Visual Stuio during build

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I opened up task manager and force closed visual studio during a build. I now get an error that says invalid or corrupt file:

1>Debug\main.obj : fatal error LNK1136: invalid or corrupt file

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select "Build" -> "Rebuild Solution" in the menu. (From memory; this might be slightly wrong)

This will delete any leftover temporary files from the last build, and rebuild the solution from scratch.